# CSS3 Transition reverse not taking effect

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, transition

I have a create two divs that overlap using `z-index` and the top one will shrink width ways but I can't get it to shrink from right to left even though I've added `animation-direction:reverse;`

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a4DUv/)

How do I change the direction of the shrink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animation-direction` is irrelevant here. That property relates to css animations. You are using `transition`s. Two different things entirely.

Give `.grow` a right position value and wrap your current `div`s in a container with relative positioning:

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4DUv/3/)

```
<div class="pos_rel">
    <div class="holder"></div> 
    <div class="grow"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.grow {
    right:0;
}
```

Also, you probably should have the `:hover` on the parent element to prevent your mouse moving out of `.grow` as it transitions:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4DUv/4/)

```
.pos_rel:hover .grow {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/venkat7668/a4DUv/2/
```

I have modified your code little bit to get your expected animation.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="grow"></div>
    <div class="holder"></div>
<div>

.main {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.holder {
    position:absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:#cccccc;
    z-index:1;
}
.grow {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transition: width 5s;
    transition: width 5s;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.grow:hover {
    width: 50px;
}
```